# Remove file with ` in name

Tags: shell, rm

At some point I created a file with: ` in it. How do I remove it?

`ls -la` returns:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user     0 Sep 25 23:01 `which
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways:

1. Quote the file name

   ```
   rm '`which'
   ```
2. Escape the offending character

   ```
   rm \`which
   ```
3. Use shell globbing (with prompting, in case there are other files that match)

   ```
   rm -i ?which
   rm -i *which
   ```
4. Use `find` instead (note that, as @Braiam pointed out below, this will find all files that match in the current directory and might delete more than you were expecting.)

   ```
   find . -name '`which' -exec rm {} \;
   find . -name '`which' -delete
   ```

Comment: remember that `find` is recursive by default, so it's recommendable to just -print the results first, to see if you are satisfied.

Comment: Is `find ... -exec rm {} \;` obsolete? What vintages of `find` don't support `-delete`?

Comment: @NickT I believe that only GNU find supports it which means that it won't work on OSX and most Unixen.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 'funny characters' in your filename and cannot type them you can do:

```
rm -i *which*
```

where `which` is the part that consists of normal characters.

The `-i` (for interactive) make sure you get prompted before removing any matching filenames, so you can skip all that match that you don't want to be deleted.

Comment: probably my favorite suggestion, but I think it didn't work for the machine (RedHat) that I was on. The command, for me, doesn't find only parts of files, and needs an exact match.

Comment: @hiyume, I had not properly looked at the formatting and missed an indent, therefore the which part was in italics instead of correctly showing the `*` characters %-)

Comment: right, that makes sense, cool :)

Answer (score 1):

That happens. If your filename is

```
`which
```

you should use

```
mv '`which' which
```

You need to use this `'` around your filename since it has a special character before the filename.

Comment: this answer was great addressing what should be done if you still needed the file, thank you

Comment: sorry i meant, rm; i thought it was rename. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it by escaping the offending character with a backslash.  You can type

```
rm \`which
```

and that will do the trick.